# Resolving permission is not denied for server files

Tags: linux

I believe this will assist more in debugging; I have a script in python that's supposed to delete a file, if I run it I get permission denied error

```
os.remove('/home/sammy/revamp/revamp/media/new_colour/' + image_name)
```

the result of ll on said image

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data 130404 Jul 19 06:49 f6bf0e0ffbe86c2c67421c5aaa695b8e.jpg*
```

and the username while logged in is `sammy`

Comment: You're probably trying to upload the file anonymously. You need to either upload to a directory that allows anyone to write to it, or you need to authenticate the uploading tool as you.

Comment: I'm using in filezilla sftp using the user sammy it works but I can't download files because they're ownership has changed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a file, you need write access on the directory which contains it. Check that your user id has that.

You mention that you are not allowed to download the file, that also looks like a problem with the directory permissions, the current file permissions should not block you from reading it.

Comment: would you know some proper settings to change folder permissions to current

Comment: Okay I need to upload a file to a folder getting permission denied.

Comment: That depends on whether you control the OS or not. You need root access to change a file or directory which belongs to another user, do you have it?

In any case, as long as you don't see "---" as the last three characters in the output of "ls -ld" for the directory, you should be allowed to read the files inside it.